# Jaxb Json diffrent behaviour in jboss and weblogic

Tags: java, jersey, jboss6.x, weblogic12c, jersey-client

Have an `jerssey V1.8` application, which is deployed in both `Jboss EAp 6.2` and `Weblogic 12c`.

In jersssey I am using `JAXB Based JSON support`.

I am facing below problems:

1- When doing a `POST` call with `null as request body`, and `content type json`, `Jboss` is processing well where as `weblogic` not able to `unmarshal` the stream to `java object` causing `NPE` and  end up with `400- Bad request`.

**End point**

```
@POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void doCreate(StringList test)
    {
}
```

**StringList class**

```
@XmlRootElement
    public class StringList
    {
        private List<String> stringList;

        public StringList()
        {
        }

        /**
         * Returns the list of string
         * @return list of string
         */
        @XmlElement(name = "value")
        public List<String> getStringList()
        {
            return stringList;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the list of string
         * @param stringList
         */
        public void setStringList(List<String> stringList)
        {
            this.stringList = stringList;
        }
    }
```

Exception Details:
Unmarshller getting used is:

```
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.JSONUnmarshallerImpl
```

from `com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider. readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream)`

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.lang.NullPointerException]
```

2- From a `GET` call, the json is not able to unmarshal back to java object in `java based RestClient`.

**Sample Json from Jboss:**

```
{
    "pageSize": 1,
    "startIndex": 0,
    "totalSize": -1,
    "items": [
        {
            "groupId": xxxxx,
            "includeDescendents": false,
            "locationIds": [
                "2"
            ],
            "roleId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

which is able to marsheled to java object properly

**Sample Output from WebLogic:**

```
{
    "pageSize": 1,
    "startIndex": 0,
    "totalSize": -1,
    "items": [
        {
            "groupId": xxxx,
            "includeDescendents": false,
            "locationIds": [
                2
            ],
            "roleId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

is not able to unmarshal back to java object.

Below part from the json output causing the issue in `weblogic`

```
"locationIds": [
                    2
                ]
```

Releveant `class`

```
private List<GroupRoleLocation> items;

@XmlRootElement
public class GroupRoleLocation implements Serializable
{

    private long groupId;
    private long roleId;

    private List<Long> locationIds;

    private boolean includeDescendents =false;
}
```

**Exception Details:**

```
JsonFormatException{text=2, line=1, column=115}
```

I am using `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext context = new org.glassfish.jersey.media.json.JsonJaxbContext(JsonConfiguration.natural().build(), objectType);`

Comment: Which exception is being thrown? Are your JAXB related dependencies included upon deployment or are the already available in the server lib directory?

Comment: @azraelAT: I have updated question with exception details, JAXB dependencies are part of the deployment

Comment: Please try switching from the glassfish impl to jersey-json (com.sun.jersey) or jackson. - the entire problem seems to be dependency related

Comment: @azraelAT: Thank you for pointing out..dependency was the main issue...